Why Are Third-Party Dependencies Not Bundling Correctly in My AAR Library?
I'm working on an Android library that I want to package as an AAR file. My library depends on some third-party libraries, and I need to ensure these dependencies are included in the AAR so that users of my library don't have to manually add them.
Here's what I've done so far:
 Added the dependencies in build.gradle using api and implementation.
 Configured the build to generate the AAR.
❓ My questions are:
Is this the correct way to bundle third-party dependencies within the AAR?
Are there any special steps I should take, like handling Proguard rules or avoiding dependency conflicts in the consuming project?
Thanks for any tips or guidance! 
In my SDK Gradle:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library)
    //id("com.android.library")
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.boltuix.prettydialoglibrary"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 25
        multiDexEnabled = true

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    api(libs.lottie)
}

In the User App's Gradle:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.boltuix.prettydialogdemo"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.boltuix.prettydialogdemo"
        minSdk = 25
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.ui.ktx)

    implementation(project(":PrettyDialogLibrary")) // working
    //implementation(files("libs/PrettyDialogLibrary-debug.aar")) // not working

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}

I created an Android library with some third-party dependencies and packaged it as an AAR. I included these dependencies in the build.gradle file using api and implementation. My expectation was that when I include this AAR in another project, the third-party libraries would be bundled and accessible without needing to add them separately.
What Actually Happened:
When I tried to use the AAR in a sample project, I encountered issues where the third-party dependencies (e.g., Lottie) were not accessible, even though they were declared in the library's build.gradle. I expected the AAR to work seamlessly, but it appears the dependencies were not properly bundled.


AARs never bundle dependencies. That's why libraries are published in Maven repositories

Building the AAR locally when it depends on third party libraries won't be useable in an application. You need to publish your library and make sure your.pom file has the dependencies you are relying on. I wrote an article that may be of assistance.
